# Uniformly distributed variable

Tags: stochastic-processes

I've stumbled upon this [correlation between two different variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326613/correlation-between-two-different-variables) thread and I can't understand this equation:

$$\mathbb{E}\cos(2\Phi+\lambda \cdot (s+t))  = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \cos(2x+ \lambda \cdot (t+s)) \, dx\text{ since }\Phi \sim U(0,2\pi)$$

Could anyone expand it?

I'm not sure if I'm right, but we might also expand it with trigonometric identities:
$\mathbb{E}\cos(2\Phi+\lambda \cdot (s+t))=\mathbb{E}\cos(2\Phi)+\mathbb{E}\cos(\lambda \cdot (s+t))-\mathbb{E}\sin(\lambda(t+s))\mathbb{E}\sin(2\Phi) $

Does it mean that $\mathbb{E}\cos(2\Phi)=\int^{2\pi}_{0}\frac{1}{2\pi} \cos(2x) \, dx$ ?

Comment: is there a $2$ missing inside the cosinus that is the integrand?

Comment: You are right about 2. I've corrected the error.

Comment: Then, as Did already answered, it is just the definition of the expected value of a function of $\Phi$.

Answer (score 1):

For *every* (say, measurable and bounded) function $u$, $E[u(\Phi)]=\frac1{2\pi}\int\limits_0^{2\pi}u(x)\mathrm dx$. This is what $\Phi$ being uniformly distributed on $(0,2\pi)$ means, actually.

Comment: Trivial. Thank you all for help!